# using reduce for an equation and an inequality. what does the # in my outcome mean?

Tags: equation-solving

This is my code

```
Manipulate[
 Reduce[{a/b^2 + 1/a == (2 b)/a^2 + 2/3 \[Beta] b && (3 v)/(
      4 \[Pi] a^2) < b < (3 v)/(2 \[Pi] a^2)}, a, Reals] // N,
 {\[Beta], 50, 200}, {v, 1*10^-9, 10*10^-9}
 ]
```

And this is the outcome i got for a certain set of beta and v

```
0.00110566 < b < 0.00139303 && 
 a == Root[-30. b^3 + 15. b^2 #1 - 1214. b^3 #1^2 + 15. #1^3 &, 1]
```

What does the # mean in this outcome?Also what I would like is something like for example;

```
a = Sqrt[b^2 + 30 b - 20]
```

So the program automaticall puts an expression of b in the place of a in another inequality for example;

```
3/(2 \[Pi]a^2) v < c < b
```

So I can find the range of c too just by selecting the values of beta and v. So what I ultimately want is the outcome

```
sth < b < sth
sth < c < sth
```

just by using one manipulate

Comment: Do read the linked thread. Briefly: read `a` as "the `1`-st `Root[]` of the polynomial `-30. b^3 + 15. b^2 x - 1214. b^3 x^2 + 15. x^3` in `x`".

Comment: Thank you now I get what # means. But I still don't know the next part of my question. How can I use that outcome to get the range of c?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If specific values of `b` are plugged into that `Root[]` expression, you get a number that is usable for subsequent bounds.

Comment: hmm okay so what I want mathematica to give me is sth like this. If 0 < x <2, x< y <2x I want 0 < y < 4. So I guess what I want is the range of y for all the possible x connected by or